# Sometimes after an object update Core Data does not persist

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have developed a framework that has its own database based on Core Data. The problem is that sometimes after an update the data changes but does not persist. And when closing and opening the application the data remains the old ones. The Core Data stack to initialize it and do the save operations is as follows:

```
import CoreData

// MARK:  - TypeAliases
typealias BatchTask=(_ workerContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> ()

// MARK:  - Notifications
enum CoreDataStackNotifications : String{
    case ImportingTaskDidFinish = "ImportingTaskDidFinish"
}

// MARK:  - Main
internal struct CoreDataStack {
    
    // MARK:  - Properties
    private let model : NSManagedObjectModel
    private let coordinator : NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
    private let modelURL : URL
    private let dbURL : URL
    private let persistingContext : NSManagedObjectContext
    private let backgroundContext : NSManagedObjectContext
    public let context : NSManagedObjectContext
    
    // MARK:  - Initializers
    public init?(modelName: String){
        
        guard let modelURL = Bundle(identifier: "com.my.framework")!.url(forResource: modelName, withExtension: "momd") else {
            MyLogger.printLog("Unable to find \(modelName)in the main bundle")
            return nil}
        
        self.modelURL = modelURL
        
        // Try to create the model from the URL
        guard let model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL) else {
            MyLogger.printLog("unable to create a model from \(modelURL)")
            return nil
        }
        self.model = model
        
        // Create the store coordinator
        coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model)
        
        // Create a persistingContext (private queue) and a child one (main queue)
        // create a context and add connect it to the coordinator
        persistingContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        persistingContext.name = "Persisting"
        persistingContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        
        context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        context.parent = persistingContext
        context.name = "Main"
        
        // Create a background context child of main context
        backgroundContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        backgroundContext.parent = context
        backgroundContext.name = "Background"
        
        // Add a SQLite store located in the documents folder
        let fm = FileManager.default
        
        guard let  docUrl = fm.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
            MyLogger.printLog("Unable to reach the documents folder")
            return nil
        }
        
        self.dbURL = docUrl.appendingPathComponent("modelMyFrameworkSDK.sqlite")
        
        
        
        do {
            try addStoreTo(coordinator: coordinator,
                           storeType: NSSQLiteStoreType,
                           configuration: nil,
                           storeURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: dbURL.absoluteString),
                           options: nil)
            
        } catch {
            MyLogger.printLog("unable to add store at \(dbURL)")
        }
    }
    
    // MARK:  - Utils
    func addStoreTo(coordinator coord : NSPersistentStoreCoordinator,
                    storeType: String,
                    configuration: String?,
                    storeURL: NSURL,
                    options : [NSObject : AnyObject]?) throws{
        
        try coord.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: dbURL, options: nil)
    }
}

// MARK:  - Removing data
extension CoreDataStack  {
    
    func dropAllData() throws{
        // delete all the objects in the db. This won't delete the files, it will
        // just leave empty tables.
        try coordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at: dbURL, ofType:NSSQLiteStoreType , options: nil)
        
        try addStoreTo(coordinator: self.coordinator, storeType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, storeURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: dbURL.absoluteString), options: nil)
    }
}

// MARK:  - Batch processing in the background
extension CoreDataStack{
    
    func performBackgroundBatchOperation(batch: @escaping BatchTask){
        
        backgroundContext.perform() {
            batch(self.backgroundContext)
            
            // Save it to the parent context, so normal saving
            // can work
            do{
                try self.backgroundContext.save()
            }catch{
                fatalError("Error while saving backgroundContext: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK:  - Heavy processing in the background.
// Use this if importing a gazillion objects.
extension CoreDataStack {
    
    func performBackgroundImportingBatchOperation(batch: @escaping BatchTask) {
        
        // Create temp coordinator
        let tmpCoord = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.model)
        
        do{
            try addStoreTo(coordinator: tmpCoord, storeType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, storeURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: dbURL.absoluteString), options: nil)
        }catch{
            fatalError("Error adding a SQLite Store: \(error)")
        }
        
        // Create temp context
        let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        moc.name = "Importer"
        moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = tmpCoord
        
        // Run the batch task, save the contents of the moc & notify
        moc.perform() {
            batch(moc)
            
            do {
                try moc.save()
            }catch{
                fatalError("Error saving importer moc: \(moc)")
            }
            
            let nc = NotificationCenter.default
            let n = Notification(name:Notification.Name(rawValue: CoreDataStackNotifications.ImportingTaskDidFinish.rawValue),
                                 object: nil)
            nc.post(n)
        }
    }
}

// MARK:  - Save
extension CoreDataStack {
    
    public func save() {
        // We call this synchronously, but it's a very fast
        // operation (it doesn't hit the disk). We need to know
        // when it ends so we can call the next save (on the persisting
        // context). This last one might take some time and is done
        // in a background queue
        context.performAndWait(){
            
            if self.context.hasChanges{
                do{
                    try self.context.save()
                }catch{
                    fatalError("Error while saving main context: \(error)")
                }
            }
            
            if self.persistingContext.hasChanges{
                
                // now we save in the background
                self.persistingContext.perform(){
                    do{
                        try self.persistingContext.save()
                    }catch{
                        fatalError("Error while saving persisting context: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if self.backgroundContext.hasChanges {
                
                self.backgroundContext.perform(){
                    do{
                        try self.backgroundContext.save()
                    }catch{
                        fatalError("Error while saving persisting context: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func autoSave(delayInSeconds : Int){
        
        if delayInSeconds > 0 {
            MyLogger.printLog("Autosaving")
            save()
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(delayInSeconds)) {
                self.autoSave(delayInSeconds: delayInSeconds)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

The creation of the objects is as shown below:

```
    public static func myObject(withData1 data1: String, data2: Bool, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> MyObject {
        
        let myObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: MyObject.entityName(), into: context) as! MyObject
        
        myObject.data1 = data1
        myObject.data2 = data2
        
        myObject.creationDate = Date()
        myObject.modificationDate = Date()
        
        return myObject
    }
```

And the update of the objects is as you can see below:

```
    public func update(withJSONObject JSONObject: [String: Any]) {
        
        guard let data1 = JSONObject["data1"] as? String else { return }
        guard let data2 = JSONObject["data2"] as? Bool else { return }
        
        self.data1 = data1
        self.data2 = data2

        self.modificationDate = Date()
    }
```

The creation and updating of the objects is done in the return callback of a call to the server.

I have tried executing these actions in the main thread in case that was the problem. And I tried to use `context.perform {}`

```
context.perform {
  object.update(withJSONObject: json)
  coreDataStack.save()
}
```

Comment: can you show what object.update((withJSONObject: json) does?

Comment: object.update((withJSONObject: json) is a mistake. The method is object.update(withJSONObject: json) and is the code just above.

Comment: have you tried breakpoints to ensure its making it all the way into "try self.context.save()" etc..?

Comment: Are you sure you are working with the right NSManagedObjectContext instance, you have so many?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I've tried with only one context and had the same problem.